# how to disable "Background items Added" notification in mac os Ventura

Tags: notifications, display-settings, macos-ventura

In mac os Venture, everytime when we start the macBook, keep getting the notification of background-Item, although I can customize which app need to run background but annoyed by repeatadely displaying and sometimes its duplcate and disabled entey

so my question is how to disable these system notification , keep things running in background, I can check .

see attached screenshot

[image: notification in mac os]

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a current bug due to migrating from a previous version of macOS and most people are forced to simply wait for an update that resolves the issue.

Consider reinstalling the offending applications. As an added precaution, once they are uninstalled visit these locations and delete the associated Google Launcher and Citrix Systems files:

/Library/LaunchAgents

/Library/LaunchDaemons

/Users/[username]/Library/LaunchAgents

After carefully deleting those files reinstall the apps and see if that fixes their associations.

Comment: Thanks for reply but in that list *Settings* is not an option and these notifications coming from system settings itself, see the icon on the notification in question, and moreover  I have already disabled few of app but still getting notification for those app also on restart of mac, especially citrix.

Comment: i did all steps but it keeps same. :/

Comment: This bug is popping up a lot. It seems to be waiting for an official fix from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick on my side:

1. `sudo sfltool resetbtm` (in a terminal of your choice).
2. Reboot.
3. Most items will legitimately re-register themselves in the database again.
4. ***In some instances***: re-register/re-install applications which did not propagate the `LoginItems`, `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDaemons` mechanisms properly. See below for some explanations.

This is how a successful reset looks like:

```shell
$ sudo sfltool resetbtm
2023-02-17 10:44:42.996 sfltool[84683:34363723] Database reset.
```

**Note**: this will irrevocably reset your whole database of registered LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, and LoginItems. For all registered users. At least until you reboot.

To kind of back up or see what you need to re-install again after this, use the following command:

```shell
$ sudo sfltool dumpbtm
[... output with all the database entries ...]
```

Normally, after reboot, most if not all of these entries should be added back properly. If you miss an auto-start application, check back with this list you prepared before resetting the database, and re-install the application accordingly.

The `sfltool`is essentially taking care of the following aspects:

```
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentServers
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.SharePoints
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.SavedSearches
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ManagedShared
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentHosts
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentDocuments
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.SessionLoginItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.AutomountedServers
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.SFLLaunchdJobs
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.SFLServiceManagementLoginItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteServers
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteVolumes
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.iCloudItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.DockApplications
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.GlobalLoginItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentApplications
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.NetworkBrowser
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ProjectsItems
com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ManagedSessionLoginItems
```

Alternatively, you might opt to install `blockblock`: https://objective-see.org/products/blockblock.html, and simply block repeated 'installations' of the same application. I haven't tried it though.

Some background on the currently chosen notification design by Apple: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depdca572563/web

I wish Apple fixed this (the issue was introduced with Ventura stock and is still present in Ventura 13.2.x). Many users are having an unpleasant experience regarding this:

- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-ventura-bug-spits-out-perpetual-background-items-added-notifications-at-login-heres-a-potential-fix.2379290/page-2
- https://piunikaweb.com/2023/02/15/macos-13-ventura-background-items-added-notification-issue/